# Effect of heavy processing on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am using setTimeout() function but i need to process heavy data inside it. I am running one loop which does some computation(time consuming). If i keep time less(here 3s) will this kill/corrupt my application during processing data or time has no effect?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {

    myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
  var x;
  for (i=0; i<1000000000000000; i++)
  {
      x=i*i*i*i;
  }
  alert("Hello!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) for long-polling tasks.

Comment: Do you get the data via AJAX? It's possible, that the AJAX call hasn't finished yet, if you'll decrease the delay to start data processing.

Comment: Yes in my case i get the data by ajax. So if it does not get finished then will it cause deadlock or hang pblm or auto killing of process?

Answer (score 1):

The callback of `setTimeout` is called after the timeout is over (3 seconds in your case). It does not matter what the callback does. But off course, your `alert` will be executed after 3 seconds **+** the time needed for the loop.

I have no idea what do you mean by data corruption here.

Answer (score 0):

IF the problem is that you don't want to have two concurrent instances of alertFunc() running, you'll have to use a mutex of some sort to solve that.

The calculation in your example will give corrupted data though, but that is caused by the fact that Numbers in javascript only have a 52 bit (iirc) precision . .